# Reduce vertical space at the bottom of a 'ruled' 'newfloat'

Tags: spacing, floats, rules

I have defined a custom float using the `newfloat` command from the `float` package. My custom float uses the ruled style, defined in the same package. This is a minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Foo}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{Foo}{Foobar}

\begin{document}

\begin{Foo}
\begin{verbatim}
public void foo(int bar) {
  foo();
  bar();
}
\end{verbatim}
\caption{An example of a foobar program}
\end{Foo}

\end{document}
```

What I don't like, is the vertical space that lies between the last line of the contents and the bottom rule of the float. Is there a way to reduce that space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the internal `\fs@ruled` macro to add a negative vertical skip before the bottom rule; add the following lines to the preamble of your document (change `-0.7\baselineskip` according to your needs):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\vskip-0.7\baselineskip\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother
```